# Android get string name from resource file values.xml

Tags: android, android-resources

I would like to get name from values `resource` file.
for example

**values.xml**

```
<string name="ind_ginger">Ginger</string>
<string name="ind_garlic">Garlic</string>
```

I am using them for the check boxes like

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/c01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/ind_garlic"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/c02"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveChanges"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/saveChanges" />
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/c02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/ind_ginger"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
```

In application I need access `String` Name ( Please note value)

```
for (CheckBox item : checkBoxList){
     if(item.isChecked())
     {
          //String text=item.getText().toString();String viewID = getResources().getResourceName(item.getId()); // gets me the name 
          String name =  getResources().getResourceEntryName(item.getId());
           String tName  =  
          //item.getText().toString();
          // String id = item.getTag().toString();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Log.d(viewID, TAG);

      }

  }
```

Is parsing the `XML` only way?

Comment: I need the string name like ind_ginger

Comment: you can get string from strings.xml by using getResources().getString(R.String.ind_ginger);

Comment: As per your explaination you are requesting for `Id` from `String.xml` using its value data. But that is not possible.

Comment: Sorry .. Yes the file name is String.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String ginger = getResources().getString(R.string.ind_ginger)
```

Comment: what I need is ind_ginger . What I am getting is "Ginger"

Comment: May I know what is the rational behind the requirement.?

Comment: Not the text string. I need the attribute name like ind_ginger  not Ginger (value) <string name="ind_ginger">Ginger</string>

Comment: Why don't you create a `HashMap` with value as the key and name as the value. so that you can get it directly right.?

Comment: They are name value pairs. needed for mapping and consistency purpose. And they are too many.

Comment: I need to know which check box check off/on

Comment: Are you using a `ListView`.?

Comment: I am not using ListView. Those check boxes are in a RelativeLayout

Comment: is it getting generated dynamically.?

Comment: That works thank you! Or the short form:         resources.getString(R.string.resource_name)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get the "KEY" name is as following:

```
Log.e("KEY_NAME", getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string.app_name));
```

Here you will get "app_name" as result.

This can be also help in support multi-language support feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to fetch all the String Keys in string.xml

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
        String[] allStringNames = new String[fields.length];
        for (int  i =0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            allStringNames[i] = fields[i].getName();
            Log.e("String Key Name",""+allStringNames[i]);
        }
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Just Store you string items in (And its better if you store your string file in in strings.xml and not value.xml  )

> strings.xml

```
 <string name="ind_ginger">Ginger</string>
    <string name="ind_garlic">Garlic</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you need `ind_ginger` you need to change your code from this

```
<string name="ind_ginger">Ginger</string>
```

to

```
<string name="ind_ginger">ind_ginger</string>
```

and

```
String ginger = getResources().getString(R.string.ind_ginger)
```

to get the `ind_ginger`.
But what I can see from your code is you are using `.getResourceEntryName(item.getId())` for that you need to create a String arraylist which would have all the itemId from strings.xml and then you can use them with item.get(position).

Here `position` is the position of the item in your array list.